# How to get around blocked ports with socket.io and NginX for multiple node apps?

Tags: node.js, nginx, websocket, socket.io

Similar questions have been asked, but I am not able to implement it correctly.

I wrote a few node js applications that are running on different ports hosted on the same IP. However these ports are blocked on some public networks such as university guest wifi, etc. I am wondering if I can set NginX properly (maybe with websocket support) to get around blocked ports on these networks. Specifically, I am wondering if I can pass visits on port 80 (which is not blocked) to their corresponding ports on localhost backend. Also I am not sure if this is the right solution for this issue. Please feel free to suggest me alternatives.

As an example suppose on the server side we have these two apps:

```
// In app1.js (server side)
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000,function(){DoSomething();};
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection',function(socket){DoStuff();};
```

and the second application:

```
// In app2.js (server side)
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const server = app.listen(3001,function(){DoSomething();};
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection',function(socket){DoStuff();};
```

and their client side codes

```
var socket = io.connect('http://mysite.domain.edu:3000');    // works, but not on public wifi
// var socket = io.connect();                                // does not work
// var socket = io.connect('http://mysite.domain.edu');      // does not work
// var socket = io.connect('http://mysite.domain.edu/app1'); // does not work
```

and the second app's client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://mysite.domain.edu:3001');
```

These apps are running separately. The NginX passes the requests to these ports with

```
# In /etc/nginx/conf.d/mysites.conf

# I am not sure about these lines, but they do not have any effect.
# map $http_connection $upgrade_requested { 
#     default upgrade;
#     ''      close;
# }

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mysite.domain.edu;
    root /home/user/mysite;

    location / {
        index /index.html;
    }

    # ap1 on port 3000
    location /app1 {
        rewrite ^/app1//(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        # I am not sure I need these.
        # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        # proxy_redirect off;
    }

    # app2 on port 3001
    location /app2 {
        rewrite ^/app2//(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        # I am not sure I need these.
        # proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        # proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        # proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        # proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

The `/etc/nginx/conf.d/mysites.conf` is my only configuration file for nginx. With these configurations, on networks where ports 3000 and 3001 are blocked, I get `xhr poll error` from `io.on('connect_error')`. In addition, if uncomment the lines in the above config file, I get the `timeout` error from `io.on('connect_error')`.

I am not sure that I am using websocket properly. Also I guess I should not specify the port when calling `io.connect('...:port')` on client side, however without specifying the port, the connection can not be established. I would appreciate it if someone can point me to my mistake or any missing config.

Comment: Yes, NGINX is the right tool for this.  You can configure multiple requests coming in on port 80 it to either route to a different port on your server based on path (different top level path segment for each of your apps) or based on incoming hostname (using a different hostname for each app that are all pointed at the same IP address of your NGINX proxy).  For socket.io connections, you could also use either path or host, but host would be easier to configure since you wouldn't have to change the client.

Comment: With socket.io, the client code `var socket = io()` will connect back to the host and port that the web page was loaded from (which is by definition always open since that's where the web page came from).  If that's what you're trying to do, then just leave the URL out of the socket.io connection entirely land the socket.io library will automatically look at `window.location` and base its connection on that host/port.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how you're already using nginx, I would recommend using a reverse proxy configuration.

If you're unfamiliar here is an example that includes redirection to port 443, based on a permanent redirect.

Provide multiple server definitions for additional apps.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name _;
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {

    listen  443 ssl; 
    ssl on;
    server_name  mydomain.tld www.mydomain.tld; #replace these with your own domain name


    location / {
       proxy_pass http://your.ip.address.here:3000;   
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
       root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```